# How to install php7.0-mcrypt package on Ubuntu os

Tags: ubuntu

`sudo apt install php7.0-mcrypt`

this command run give me this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.0-mcrypt : Depends: libmcrypt4 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
```

I have no idea what can i do. Please give suggestions to solve this problem 
and thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

sudo apt install libmcrypt4 php7.0-mcrypt

alternately you could do like
sudo apt -f install php7.0-mcrypt

giving -f as parameter will install all the unmet dependencies and follow to install the package you have given.
 [reference link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=17103)

Comment: sudo apt-get build-dep libmcrypt4
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for libmcrypt4

Comment: sudo apt-get build-dep libmcrypt4

Comment: sudo apt update && sudo apt -f install php7.0-mcrypt